# how to integrate rest-template in GWT application

Tags: gwt

Im new to GWT. Is there any way to get an object from webservice in GWT using Spring Rest-Template like Android. If there is any example project then please mention that link. thanks

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate RPC with Spring on the server side with [gwt-rpc](https://code.google.com/p/gwtrpc-spring/).

If this is a small project, that's the way I would go.

If this is a longer term project, there are advantages to having a clean REST API to separate client and server code, though it is significantly more work up front. If you go down that path, you might just want to enable the new JSON libraries in [GWT 2.7](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_7_0)

Cheers,

```
       Emily
```